# Is there a way to disable notifications from SF updates?

Tags: service-cloud-console

please see the screenshot below for an example of what I'm talking about, this keeps popping up for our Service Agents while they are on calls and getting in the way.  Is there a way to disable or dismiss these for everyone, or at least certain profiles in our org? Or maybe just disable them within our custom service console lightning app?

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling **Standard Salesforce Prompts** under **Setup** > **In-App Guidance**?

[image: Setup - in-app guidance]

Comment: That's the ticket, thanks!